# Помогите преобразовать строку

Tags: python

Для доступа к реестру хочу использовать winreg.

**пример из интернета:**

```
Winreg(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1")
```

**я хочу использовать приблизительно такую функцию:**

```
def addreg(r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1')
```

**Вопрос 1:** Как вырезать из строки HKEY_CURRENT_USER ?

**Вопрос 2:** Есть ли в функционале python функция преобразующая строку 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER' в ссылку winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

(нехочется писать if ... Winreg(winreg...) 5 раз для каждого раздела реестра)

Comment: Что в данном случае означает "вырезать"?

Comment: Разбить строку HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1 внутри функции на 2 подстроки: HKEY_CURRENT_USER и \\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1

Comment: Вырезать первую часть из строки проще всего new_str = old_str[:old_str.find('\\')]

Comment: @Roman Bolshevik, сделал так как в ответе, ваш вариант лучше? чем? Если да добавьте ответ.

Comment: Может я чего-то не допонимаю, но в чём смысл этого цикла? У нас значение HKEY все равно всегда первым стоит. Зачем нам что-то искать, если можно просто рубить строку на 2 части до первого слэша. Если у нас будет набор таких строк, то по ним вообще лучше генератором пройтись:

Comment: @Roman Bolshevik, напишите пожалуйста ваш пример...? (уточняю, нужно одну строку разбить на две, чтобы была возможность применить как первую, так и вторую.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забить словарь соответствий строк ключам и вытаскивать значения через него.

```
import winreg

keys_map = {
    "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"     : winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT    ,
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"     : winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER    ,
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"    : winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE   ,
    "HKEY_USERS"            : winreg.HKEY_USERS           ,
    "HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA" : winreg.HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
    "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"   : winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
}
def str2key(fullkey):
    root, subkey = fullkey.split(r"\\", 1)
    if root in keys_map:
        return (keys_map[root], subkey)
    print(f"Unknown root key '{root}'")
    
print(str2key(r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1'))
print(str2key(r'WTF\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test2'))
```

```
(18446744071562067969, 'SOFTWARE\\\\RegTest\\\\test1')
Unknown root key 'WTF'
None
```

Ну а дальше можно подстановкой через звёздочку, а можно ручками через переменные.

```
Winreg(*str2key(r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1'))
# или
key, subkey = str2key(r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1')
Winreg(key, subkey)
```

Comment: То есть можно в принципе и названия функций забивать аналогичным образом, верно?

Comment: Все хорошо, только вот ошибку выдает... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\tokey.py", line 23, in <module>
    winreg.CreateKey(tokey(r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\SelectStyle'))
TypeError: CreateKey() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Значит ошибка уже в вашем коде. Звёздочку напишите перед `tokey`.

Comment: Все правильно, я про ваше сообщение со звездочкой запамятовал..., все работает, либо через звездочку либо через переменные. уже сам допер. :) Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на вопрос 1:** (Цикл ищет каждое значение из списка keys в строке str, если нашел присваивает значение key и переопределяет строку str с вырезанным значением key.)

```
str = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\RegTest\\test1"
key = None
keys = {'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT',
        'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
        'HKEY_USERS',
        'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG'}

for i in keys:
    k = str.find(i)
    if k != -1:
        key = i
        str = str.replace(key, '')

if key == None:
    print('Error: key not found in str!')

print(key, str)
```